# System Integrity event on wpshelper.sys

Tags: windows-7, security

In the Windows Event Viewer, I noticed many events of type 5038 "System Integrity", with the following text:

```
Code integrity determined that the image hash of a file is not valid.  The file could be corrupt due to unauthorized modification or the invalid hash could indicate a potential disk device error.

File Name:  \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\drivers\wpshelper.sys
```

The disk is new so a disk failure is not probable. Is this a virus? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when the drivers are not digitally signed.

To solve, you can try:

1. Do a scan with [`chkdsk`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872425.aspx) looking for corrupt files.
2. For you know if the file has changed or not, compare the file hash with what is said here([`Malware scan of WpsHelper`](http://www.herdprotect.com/wpshelper.sys-5855a96bc98a03e6d7f0d05c000276104fc89eb4.aspx)).

---

*`WpsHelper`* is a driver file from company Symantec Corporation belonging to product Symantec Intrusion Detection.

Good luck.